# Sum function prob TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

Tags: python, sum, typeerror, operand, operands

I'm new to python (PYTHON 3.4.2) and I'm trying to make a program that adds and divides to find the average or the mean of a user's input, but I can't figure out how to add the numbers I receive.

When I open the program at the command prompt it accepts the numbers I input and would print it also if I use a print function, but it will not sum the numbers up.

I receive this error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

My code is below:

```
#Take the user's input
numbers = input("Enter your numbers followed by commas: ")
sum([numbers])
```

Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: will you please give full traceback ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`input` takes a input as string

```
>>> numbers = input("Enter your numbers followed by commas: ")
Enter your numbers followed by commas: 1,2,5,8
>>> sum(map(int,numbers.split(',')))
16
```

you are telling user to give input saperated by comma, so you need to split the string with comma, then convert them to int then sum it

demo:

```
>>> numbers = input("Enter your numbers followed by commas: ")
Enter your numbers followed by commas: 1,3,5,6
>>> numbers
'1,3,5,6'   # you can see its string
# you need to split it
>>> numbers = numbers.split(',')
>>> numbers
['1', '3', '5', '6']
# now you need to convert each element to integer
>>> numbers = [ x for x in map(int,numbers) ]
or
# if you are confused with map function use this:
>>> numbers  = [ int(x) for x in numbers ]
>>> numbers
[1, 3, 5, 6]
#now you can use sum function
>>>sum(numbers)
15
```

Answer (score 0):

[`input`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input) will give you string, and you are trying to concat string with int.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code. It works for me. Actually `input()` tries to run the input as a Python expression. But the `raw_input()` takes the input as string. `input()` exists in Python 3.x.You can find more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4915361/whats-the-difference-between-raw-input-and-input-in-python3-x)

```
numbers = input("Enter your numbers followed by commas: ") ## takes numbers as input as expression
print sum([i for i in numbers]) ## list comprehension to convert the numbers into invisible list. This is done because `sum()` runs only on iterable and list is iterable.
```

Output:

```
Enter your numbers followed by commas: 1,2,3,4
10
```

Comment: Yeah I have Python 3.4, so I tried your code but used "eval(input())" instead of "input()" and it worked, thanks

Answer (score 0):

First you need to convert elements of "numbers" to int, no need to strip the comma or whitespaces. This code is pretty straight forward and works fine.

```
numbers = input("Enter your numbers followed by commas: ")

numbers_int = [int(x) for x in numbers]

numbers_sum = sum(numbers_int)

print numbers_sum
```

Comment: I received a ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ","

Comment: How do you input your numbers? I tested it like this: 2, 3, 4 and so on. Update: I tested it with "2 , 3 , 4" and "2 , 3 , 4," and other possible variants, and it works.

Comment: Oh I think it's because im using python 3.x.x, so instead of "input()" I have to use "eval(input())" for the same results. When I did that it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Simple: the list elements are stored as string :) So you have to convert all of them to int